# Elegant way to drop rest of a string at the occurence of a character

Tags: string-manipulation

For example, I have a string `"ahfiehfke$jfwfjejf0"`. Is there an elegant way to drop all characters after `"$"`? I know loop through and `StringDrop` till we hit the `"$"` would work, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: `First@StringSplit["ahfiehfke$jfw$fje$jf0", "$", 2]`

Comment: @belisarius beat me to it.

Comment: `First[StringCases["ahfiehfke$jfwfjejf0", ___ ~~ "$", 1]]`

Comment: @Coolwater Your version fails when there are more than one `$` in the string. The correct version: `First[StringCases[str, Shortest[___] ~~ "$", 1]]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
StringTrim["ahfiehfke$jfwfjejf0", "$" ~~ __];

StringDelete["ahfiehfke$jfwfjejf0", "$" ~~ __]; (*V10.1*)
```

Answer (score 2):

A bunch of regex methods:

```
str = "ahfiehfke$jfwfjejf0";

(* Coolwater *)
StringCases[str, RegularExpression["(?s).+?\\$", 1]][[1]]

StringReplace[str, RegularExpression["(?s)\\$.*"] :> "$", 1]
```

These use look-behind regexes:

```
StringReplace[str, RegularExpression["(?s)(?<=\\$).+"] :> "", 1]

StringTrim[str, RegularExpression["(?<=\\$).+"]]
```

(Thanks to Alexey for pointing out the need to properly handle newline characters.)

Comment: Note that both `StringReplace` solutions fail if the string contains a newline character `\n` after `"$"`. You need to add the `(?s)` option to fix this.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks @Alexey.

Comment: ... and the `StringCases` version fails if the string contains a newline character *before* `$`: it also needs the `(?s)` modifier. Only the `StringTrim` version works correctly without it because for `StringTrim` this modifier is already switched on internally.

Comment: The `StringCases` version also works incorrectly when there are more than one `$` in the string. The correct version: `StringCases[str, RegularExpression["(?s).+?\\$"], 1][[1]]`.

Comment: Ah, that's what I get for trying to answer without a computer. :D Thanks again, @Alexey.

Answer (score 1):

Another method:

```
StringTake[str, StringPosition[str, "$", 1][[1, 1]]]
```

A comparison of performance of different methods which give identical results:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
str = StringJoin@{Table["a", {1000}], Table["ahfieh\nfke$jfw\nfje$jf0", {1000}]};
Replace[Hold[{
     StringTrim[str, "$" ~~ __] <> "$",
     StringDelete[str, "$" ~~ __] <> "$",
     First@StringSplit[str, "$", 2] <> "$",
     First[StringCases[str, Shortest[___] ~~ "$", 1]],
 StringCases[str, RegularExpression["(?s).+?\\$"], 1][[1]],
     StringReplace[str, RegularExpression["(?s)\\$.*"] :> "$", 1],
     StringReplace[str, RegularExpression["(?s)(?<=\\$).+"] :> "", 1],
 StringTrim[str, RegularExpression["(?<=\\$).+"]],
     StringTake[str, StringPosition[str, "$", 1][[1, 1]]]
     }], x_ :> {HoldForm@x, AccurateTiming@x}, {2}] // 
  ReleaseHold // TableForm
```

> [image: table]

It seems that the absolute winner is:

```
StringReplace[str, RegularExpression["(?s)\\$.*"] :> "$", 1]
```